# How to align the text of the header in left align in jQuery Mobile?

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

How do I align the text of the header to left align in [jQuery Mobile](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JQuery_Mobile)?

I have specified it like the following.

```
<div data-role=header data-theme="b">
    <h1 align="left"><font size="1px"> My Contacts -> Doctor </font></h1>
</div>
```

but it is not appearing. I just wanted to align the `text in the header`, and I also need to resize the text size.

Comment: Off-topic, but you should really use a proper arrow, `→` or `&rarr;`. The `->` looks unprofessional. This is not 1950.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe this can help you:

```
<div data-role=header data-theme="b" style="text-align: left;font-size: 10px;">
    My Contacts -> Doctor 
</div>
```